# Start Plasma-Desktop with parameters

Tags: nvidia-optimus, kde4, plasma

Is it possible to start plasma-desktop after login with parameters?
E.g. if I want to try my Optimus:

```
DRI_PRIME=1 plasma-desktop
```

And if so, how can I show if the nVidia card is used?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like editing `/usr/share/autostart/plasma-desktop.desktop` is what you need.

AFAIU you just need to add `DRI_PRIME=1` right after `Exec=`

The file found by looking into `/usr/share/xsessions/kde-plasma.desktop` and `/usr/bin/startkde`

Comment: Allright, I did that, but how can I check if plasma-desktop use nvidia optimus and not the intel driver?

Comment: I thought you know the difference :) From my previous experience with dual GPU notebooks it should be much hotter. But that's far from the best method. Maybe try banchmarking with and without DRI_PRIME.

Comment: Hehe, I should seee the difference :) But it's not obviously hotter. Therefore I asked. Trying to benchmark today.